# Whats the minimum and maximum length of WPA3 Personal password?

Tags: wifi, wpa

Trying to find out what the criteria of a WPA3 Personal wifi password should be. Is it consistent with WPA2 PSK (8-63 ASCII characters)?

Checked the wifi spec and didn't see anything that mentioned minimum and maximum length

Answer (score 2):

Per IEEE 802.11-2020, an SAE password is a UTF-8 string that is composed entirely of code points that are explicitly allowed by the FreeformClass string class defined in RFC8264, processed according to the OpaqueString profile of IETF RFC 8265, the output of which is an octet string. The min and max length are undefined.

Since WAP2-Personal implementations are intended to transition to WPA3-Personal, most implementations that I have seen use the same constraints as WPA2. For example, Android uses 8 to 63 characters: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/heads/master/hostapd/hostapd.conf#1881. It looks like Linux allows up to 128 bytes: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/ieee80211.h#L3601.